# Show Edit Text in Text View, & adjust height according to Content written in Edit text (Android)

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-studio, android-activity

When i send message or joke of 1 Line or 1 word, then why so much space is left at bottom. I  take text view as `wrap_content`.

[image]

I need text to be wrapped to its height. What I needed is shown in the picture below.
[image]

### Text View

```
    <TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
    android:text=""
    android:ems="10"
    android:gravity="top|left"
    android:hint="Enter Message"
    android:inputType="textMultiLine|textPostalAddress"
    android:minHeight="200dip"
    android:padding="5dip"
    android:scrollbars="vertical"
    android:layout_marginTop="-5dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="-5dp"
    android:textColor="@color/blue"
    android:maxLines="1000000"
    android:id="@+id/messageDetail"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/linearLayout4" />
```

### Edit Text, both are in different Activities

```
       <EditText
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:ems="10"
    android:gravity="top|left"
    android:hint="Enter Message"
    android:id="@+id/sendTextView"
    android:inputType="textMultiLine|textPostalAddress"
    android:minHeight="200dip"
    android:minWidth="390dp"
    android:editable="true"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:cursorVisible="true"
    android:scrollbars="vertical"
    android:background="@color/gray"
    android:padding="@dimen/fab_margin"
    android:layout_above="@+id/camera"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />
```

Comment: post your xml code here..

Comment: Brother, posted my XML. also want to say that, in XML i tried almost everything given in StackOverFlow.

Answer (score 0):

Try this to adjust `height` according to Content written in Edit text,

```
               <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/editMsj"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:ems="10"
                    android:gravity="top|left"
                    android:hint="Enter Message"
                    android:inputType="textMultiLine|textPostalAddress"
                    android:minHeight="200dip"
                    android:padding="5dip"
                    android:scrollbars="vertical"
                    android:textColor="@color/black"
                    android:textColorHint="#80000000"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/font_normal_size" />
```

For TextView, here i have added `android:ellipsize="end"` , `android:maxLines="20"` , `android:singleLine="false"`

```
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/messageDetail"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:hint="Your Message"
        android:maxLines="20" //number of lines to restrict in textview
        android:padding="5dip"
        android:singleLine="false" />
```

Hope this helps

Comment: give enter to this edittext and it will increase its height. than what else you need ?

Comment: No its not working yet. Actually, i'm writing message in Edit text, and trying to show it in Text View in next Activity.. but it gives me too much space below. the above pictures are of Text View.  I'm trying to send my Java file. Kindly go through it. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: I took Video View, Image View and Text View in a single XML, and give path to all simultaneously. Images and Videos are working perfectly, but Text View capturing extra space below.

Comment: No brother, it is same.

Comment: It is working on my machine. you might be doing something wrong. tested my ans and than posted answer.

Comment: okay. here ImageVIew and TextView are different so that will happen. remove extrapadding and margins.

Comment: I removed it from Edit Text And Text View, its not working brother...  now from where i have to remove extra padding and margins??

Comment: that much space will be there because you have used imageview below textview.

Comment: do you want that textview between that two images ?

Comment: no brother, I want to upload Videos, Images and Texts in a single Layout.. by switching when somebody Texts it will go to Text View, if Somebody send images it will show in Image View and so on..

Answer (score 0):

`TextView` and `Edittext` have space left at bottom , because of  `android:minWidth` attribute.

`android:minWidth` is used for given the minimum height to your view.

Try Below Code:

**TextView**

```
 <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:text=""
        android:ems="10"
        android:gravity="top|left"
        android:hint="Enter Message"
        android:inputType="textMultiLine|textPostalAddress"
        android:padding="5dip"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        android:layout_marginTop="-5dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="-5dp"
        android:textColor="#15ADEC"
        android:maxLines="1000000"
        android:id="@+id/messageDetail"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/linearLayout4" />
```

**EditText**

```
<EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:gravity="top|left"
        android:hint="Enter Message"
        android:id="@+id/sendTextView"
        android:inputType="textMultiLine|textPostalAddress"
        android:minWidth="390dp"
        android:editable="true"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:cursorVisible="true"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        android:padding="@dimen/fab_margin"
        android:layout_above="@+id/camera"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />
```

I hope its work for you.